# Can we create arrays with for loop, without square bracket in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, brackets

Im new at javascript. Please help me.

Can we create arrays with for loop, without square bracket.
Like :

```
var ar0 = num0
var ar1 = num1
.
.
var ar"i" = num"i"
```

i cant define like that :

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){

var (ar+i) = num+i

}
```

i know this isnt array but i want create a lot like this. i have to use "for loop"

Comment: Relevant: ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 let result={};
    for (let i=0;i<5;i++){
        result["ar"+i]= `num${i}`;
    }
    console.log(result);
```

The result will be something like this:

> { ar0: 'num0', ar1: 'num1', ar2: 'num2', ar3: 'num3', ar4: 'num4' }

I hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I only see that as a solution  :

```
let ar = Array.from({length:5},(_,i)=>`num${i}`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use eval built-in function :

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    eval("var " "ar"+i + "= num+"i)
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `eval` unless you point out the potential catastrophes with using `eval`